# Subprocess не хочет выполнять команду | Совместить выполенние команды subprocess с os.system

Tags: python

[Windows]

Столкнулся с проблемой, а именно:
subprocess не хочет выполнять команду chcp 65001

```
import supbrocess
subprocess.call(["cmd", "chcp 65001"], shell=True)
```

Этот вариант работать не будет. Просто открывается консоль и все, но если использовать os.system - то все работает.

```
import os
os.system("chcp 65001")
```

Но проблема в том, что при выполнении открывается окно консоли, а нужно чтобы консоли не было.

Как совместить выполнение кода subprocess с os.system? Или же как убрать консоль при выполнении os.system("chcp 65001")

Comment: Попробуйте варианты: subprocess.call(["cmd.exe","chcp","65001"],shell = True)  или 
 subprocess.call(["chcp","65001"],shell = True)

Comment: я так понимаю, что проблема для 2 питона, т.к. в 3 питоне по умолчанию юникод и все должно нормально работать и без изменения кодовой страницы?

Comment: @АлексейОбухов 
Разобрался, нужно было подставить "shell=True", но возникла проблема при компиляции в exe через pyinstaller с аргументом --noconsole (мне важно, чтобы консоли не было при запуске exe файла)

Answer (score -2):

Нужно было просто подставить `shell=True`

Comment: У нас принято, что вопросы задаются в новой теме. Удалил вопрос, оставил только ответ.